# Find current display screen dimensions where my WPF application is running

Tags: c#, wpf

I am able to find all the screens dimensions using below code but how can I find which screen my application is about to run?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       int length = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Screen_PrimaryScreen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WindowInteropHelper` to get a handle of your window. Then use the `Screen.FromHandle` method to obtain the [Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=netcore-3.1) which offers more information like Bounds, BitsPerPixel, etc..

The [Screen.FromHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.fromhandle?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Screen_FromHandle_System_IntPtr_) method works as stated by the docs:

> A Screen for the display that contains the largest region of the
> object. In multiple display environments where no display contains any
> portion of the specified window, the display closest to the object is
> returned.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Windows.Interop;
    
    namespace WpfApp2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
    
            private readonly WindowInteropHelper _windowInteropHelper;
    
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    
                LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
            }
    
            private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(_windowInteropHelper.Handle);
                Debug.WriteLine($"IsPrimary: {screen.Primary}, Bounds: {screen.Bounds}");
            }
    
        }
    }
```

If you want to get rid of System.Windows.Forms you need to write your own Wrapper class around the [Multiple Display Monitors Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-display-monitors-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)